# Button inside a span, both have an event. If I click the button, the span event also starts

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<span onClick={'event example 1'}>
  content example 1
  <button onClick={'event example 1'}>
    content example 2
  </button> 
</span>
```

How can I press the button without also involving the span event? It's possible?

Comment: Your event function should probably check for the `event.currentTarget`, which I believe is the element that the event is actually assigned to (not its children).

Comment: Fix code examples

Comment: Why did you put ** around the element names?

Comment: Do you have separate event handlers for each element, or are they calling the same handler?

Comment: @user3425506, I made a mistake, I corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example. you have to bind event to get access to stop   event.stopPropagation()

```js
function spanFunction(e) {
  console.log('spanFunction')
}

function buttonFunction(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  console.log('buttonFunction')
}
```

```html
<span onClick="spanFunction(event)">
  content example 1
  <button onClick="buttonFunction(event)">
    content example 2
  </button> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two extra properties to handle this issue:

1. event.preventDefault is to prevent the default action of the
   element.
2. event.stopPropagation is to stop the event from propagating
   upwards.

In your handler specify first attribute - event and in html bind the function with event. In this case you need to use stopPropagation.

```
onClick(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('button element');
});
```

Comment: `preventDefault` shouldn't be relevant here. `stopPropogation` is the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

Events bubble by default. So the target is the element that triggered the event (e.g., the user clicked on).

If u face some ambiguity while stopping the event bubbling via ***stopPropogation***(preferred) u can this structure.

```js
// Dont forget to pass event (e).
if (e.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
  conosole.log('CLICK');
}
```

Comment: Code snippet off topic